# Matrices and Geometric Series

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been given the following question as part of an assignment:
    "Consider the $N \times N$ matrices $H_0$ and $V$; consider the matrix $G$ defined by $G=(zI - H_0 - V)^{-1}$ where $z$ is a scalar and $I$ is the identity matrix. Let $G_0 = (zI - H_0)^{-1}$. Show that $G$ can be written as

$$
G = G_0 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (V G_0)^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (G_0 V)^n G_0
$$

It also says to formally use the following geometric series on the $ G=(zI - H_0 - V)^{-1} $ equation:

$$
\frac{1}{1 - x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n, \quad \mbox{for } |x| < 1
$$

I am unsure how exactly to directly apply this geometric series onto the $ G=(zI - H_0 - V)^{-1}$ equation.  I suspect that there is some property to relate $VG_0$ and $G$?   I would appreciate if someone would be able to steer me in the right direction.  Thanks.

Comment: See the user Theo Bendit's answer to my question, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4246253/815585). I haven't fully digested your question, but this may help you

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** The geometric series in matrix form is:
$$
(I-A)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A^n
$$ 
when $\|A\|<1$. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867768/geometric-series-of-matrices) can also help.

Comment: I am unsure how exactly to now apply that series.  Would I set A = G or G0?  Or VG0?