# Does the same series closed formulas apply for matrices

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, convergence-divergence

let's say I have the following series:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}x^n$$
which converges to 
$$ \frac{1}{1-x}$$
Does this also work if $x$ was an $N \times N$ matrix?

Comment: What does $\frac{1}{1-x}$ mean in the context of matrices?

Comment: Take a look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867768/geometric-series-of-matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does, although you should probably rephrase it a bit.
For a matrix $X$ with operator norm $\lVert X \rVert < 1$, you can indeed sum
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty X^n = (1-X)^{-1}.
$$
You can prove it very similarly to the original case where $X$ is just a number.

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Given $1 \le p \lt \infty$, the matrix form is given in this lemma:

If $\mathbf{F}\in\mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ and $\lVert \mathbf{F} \rVert_p \lt 1$
then the matrix $\mathbf{I}_m - \mathbf{F}$ is nonsingular and 
$$
  \left( \mathbf{I}_m - \mathbf{F} \right)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathbf{F}
$$
and 
$$
 \lVert \left( \mathbf{I}_m - \mathbf{F} \right)^{-1} \rVert_{p} \le \frac{1}{1-\lVert \mathbf{F}\rVert_{p} }
$$

[Matrix Computations 3e](https://jhupbooks.press.jhu.edu/content/matrix-computations), 
Golub & Van Loan,  Lemma 2.3.3, p 58

---

Compare the scalar convergence criteria 
$$
 \lvert x \rvert \lt 1
$$
with the matrix convergence criteria
$$
\lVert \mathbf{F} \rVert_{p} \lt 1
$$