# Does $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+\cdots$ work for certain matrices?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

In real analysis, there's a theorem saying that for all real $x$ with $|x| <1$, we have: $$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+\cdots$$

> **Question.** Does a version of this apply to certain matrices, thereby giving us a convenient way of approximating $(1-A)^{-1}$? If so, for which matrices is this formula correct?

Comment: I've just googled "Geometric series of matrices" and the first result gives an answer to this.

Comment: Yes, as long as $A^n \to 0$.

Comment: I would imagine if all eigenvalues are in the unit circle.

Comment: there are "induced norms" on matrices, perhaps other submultiplicative ones, the analogous result applies using those. Also called operator norms

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867768/geometric-series-of-matrices

Comment: @Gregory, you mean unit ball, right? According the conventions I'm familiar with, the unit circle is merely the boundary of the unit ball.

Comment: I said "in" not "on", I thought there was a difference. Also unit ball implies higher than 2D and eigenvalues live in the complex plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, this works for matrices $A$ with $\|A\|<1$ and is known as [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series). The proof is basically the same as for numbers…

Comment: Notably, $\|\cdot \|$ here can be any submultiplicative matrix-norm.

Answer (score 5):

If the series $\sum_{n\ge 0} A^n$ converges, then its sum is $(I-A)^{-1} $ since $(I-A)(1+ A+ \cdot + A^{n}) = I - A^{n+1} \to I$.

Now, we have the following equivalent statements:

1. The series $\sum_{n\ge 0} A^n $ is convergent
2. $A^{n} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$
3. All of the eigenvalues of $A$ have absolute value $< 1$.

1.$\implies$ 2. is clear, let's check 2.$\implies$ 1. Assume $A^n\to 0$. Then for $n$ large enough the matrix $(I-A^{n+1}$ is invertible, and so $I- A$ also is ( from the above). Therefore, $\sum_{k=0}^n A^k = (I-A^{n+1})(I-A)^{-1} \to (I-A)^{-1}$.

2. $\implies$ 3. follows from the fact that if $\{\lambda_i\}$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ then $\{\lambda_i^n\}$ are the eigenvalues of $A^n$
3. $\implies 2$. Use the Jordan canonical form, it's enough to check for a Jordan cell $J_{\lambda, d}$ with $|\lambda|< 1$.

As an observation, if for a certain submultiplicative norm $||\cdot ||$  on the algebra of matrices we have $||A||< 1$ then $A^n \to 0$, but the converse is not true.

Comment: " if {λ_i} are the eigenvalues of A then {λ_i^n} are the eigenvalues of A." that last A should be A^n

Comment: @Nitin: Oh yea, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this works for matrices A with $r(A)<1$ and is known as Neumann series. The proof is the same as for numbers. Here $r(A)$ is the spectral radius of $A$:

$$r(A)= \lim_{n \to \infty}\|A^n\|^{1/n}.$$

($\|\cdot\| $ is a submultiplictive norm)

In this case we have that $I-A$ is invertible and

$$(I-A)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A^n.$$

Answer (score 2):

As long as the series on the right-hand side converges, so that it's well-defined, you can perform the multiplication
$$
(I-A)(I+A+A^2+\cdots)
$$and see that you do indeed end up with $I$, which means that the two are inverses of one another.

One can, of course, make this result strict with $\epsilon$-$\delta$ and partial sums. It shouldn't be more difficult than most $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs.