# Proof of the equation of the fundamental matrix in absorbing Markov chains

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

The standard or canonical form of the transition matrix of an absorbing Markov chain is

$$P = \begin{bmatrix}I & 0 \\ R & Q \end{bmatrix}$$

and the fundamental matrix is calculated as

$$F=(I - Q)^{-1}$$

such that $FR$ spells out the probability of eventually landing on each absorbing states from different transient states. At the same time, $F$ provides the expected number of steps required.

> What is the proof that $F$ and $FR$ include this information?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain

Comment: @amd Thanks! I had gone to that page, but I didn't see the derivation. You caught me typing an answer in case it can help someone else.

Answer (score 7):

The submatrix $R$ contains the transition probabilities from transient to absorbing states, while $Q$ contains the transition probabilities from transient to transient states.

Powers of the transition matrix $P$ approach a limiting matrix with a pattern:

$$\begin{align}
P^2 &=\begin{bmatrix}I & 0 \\ R & Q \end{bmatrix}^2= \begin{bmatrix}I & 0 \\ R+QR & Q^2 \end{bmatrix}\\[3ex]
P^3 &=\begin{bmatrix}I & 0 \\ R+QR & Q^2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I & 0 \\ R & Q \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}I & 0 \\ R+QR+Q^2R & Q^3 \end{bmatrix}\\[3ex]
P^k &=\begin{bmatrix}I & 0 \\ \left(I+Q+Q^2+\cdots+Q^{k-1}\right)R & Q^k \end{bmatrix}\tag 1
\end{align}$$

The key now is that $Q^k\to 0$ as $k\to \infty.$

The fundamental matrix is a [geometric series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/867768/152225):

$$F= I+Q+Q^2+\cdots=(I-Q)^{-1}$$

and replacing the expression $I+Q+Q^2+\cdots+Q^{k-1}$ in (1) with $F:$

$$\begin{align}P^{\infty}&=\begin{bmatrix}I & 0 \\ FR & 0 \end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

Comment: I think answer should read "The submatrix $R$..." at the begining