# Geometric Series of Discounted Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, geometric-series

Does the following series have a closed form solution for scalar $\gamma$ 
 and vector $x$ such that $0 \leq \gamma < 1$?

$$ (M + \gamma M + \gamma^2M^2 + \gamma^3M^3 +\ldots + \gamma^\infty M^\infty )x
$$

Much like how the scalar version does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\|M\|\leq 1$, [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867768/geometric-series-of-matrices) we have $(I + \gamma M + \gamma^2M^2 + \gamma^3M^3 +\ldots)=(I-\gamma M)^{-1}$. So a closed form solution would be
$$\left((M-I)+(I-\gamma M)^{-1}\right)x=Mx-Ix+(I-\gamma M)^{-1}x$$
(given that $\|\gamma M\|<1$).